# Gradle - configure subprojects based on plugin presence

Tags: gradle, plugins, subproject

I am fighting with a fairly simple gradle problem but despite searching I cannot find a solution.
Very simple, in a multi project build, I need configure some subproject based on the plugins they load. So
If sub project has plugin 'war' or 'ear' do this..
I have tried the following without success:

```
subprojects {
    if (it.plugins.hasPlugin('war') || (it.plugins.hasPlugin('ear') {
        apply plugin: 'my super special plugin'
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

The above never apply plugin: 'my super special plugin'

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Gradle executes `subprojects` closure before evaluating build.gradle from subprojects. Therefore, there are no information about plugins from `build.gradle` at this point.
To execute some code after evaluation of the `subproject/build.gradle` you should use [ProjectEvaluationListener](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/ProjectEvaluationListener.html).
For example:

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
      if (it.plugins.hasPlugin('war') || (it.plugins.hasPlugin('ear') {
          it.plugins.apply 'my super special plugin'
          ....
          ....
      }
    }
}
```

Also note about `it.plugins.apply 'my super special plugin'` instead of `apply plugin: 'my super special plugin'`

Another option is to use shared `common.gradle` wich will configure subprojects. This shared gradle file may be included in the `subproject/build.gradle` by using `apply from: '../common.gradle'` in proper place.